# How to extract deviance residuals for each observation for multinom() -objects?

Tags: r, multinomial

After fitting a mutlinomial logit model using the `multinom()` function, I want to extract the deviance residuals for each obervation.

Since for a binary logit model I normally use:

```
n = 1000
df1 = data.frame(x1=runif(n,0,100),x2=runif(n,0,100))
df1 = transform(df1,y=1+ifelse(100 - x1 - x2 + rnorm(n,sd=10) < 0, 0,                  ifelse(100 - 2*x2 + rnorm(n,sd=10) < 0, 1, 2)), set="Original")

df1$y_binary=ifelse(df1$y==1,1,0)
logit_model=glm(y:binary ~x1+x2,data=df1,family=binomial(link='logit'))

eps=resid(logit_model,type="deviance")
```

I want to compute the counterpart for the multinomial regression model, having set up:

```
library(nnet)
mod <- multinom(y ~ x1 + x2, df1)
```

So how to proceede to get de deviance residuals out of `mod`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems there is no such function for models fitted with `nnet::multinom()`.

If you take a look at `multinom()` function body, you will see that the deviance is calculated from a total value `fit$deviance <- 2 * fit$value`. This value is the same as you have in `mod$value` - it is the likelihood ratio test statistic. Hence, you have only the total number for Deviance.

However, you can implement your own function. For each observation, after calculating the deviance, you only have to choose a rule for setting the deviance value signal. Here is a link to a paper that proposes a signed extended method to calculate deviance residuals in multinomial models: http://convegni.unica.it/cladag2015/files/2015/10/Romeo1.pdf.